# Plot coefficients for one year

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a list of 701 given `csv` files. Each one has the same number of columns (7) but different number of rows (between 25000 and 28000).

Here is an extract of the first file:

```
Date,Week,Week Day,Hour,Price,Volume,Sale/Purchase
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-3000.00,17416,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-1001.10,17427,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-1000.00,18055,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-500.10,18057,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-500.00,18064,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-400.10,18066,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-400.00,18066,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-300.10,18068,Sell
18/03/2011,11,5,1,-300.00,18118,Sell
```

Now I am trying to plot the coefficients of my following regression (in the price intervall -50 and 150) of the supply curve for the ninth hour over one year.

First I made the regression:

```
allenamen <- dir(pattern="*.csv")
alledat <- lapply(allenamen, read.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
h <- list()
for(i in 1:length(alledat)){
g <- function(a, b, c, d, p) {a*atan(b*p+c)+d}
f <- nlsLM(Volume ~ g(a,b,c,d,Price), data=subset(alledat[[i]], (Hour==9) & (Sale.Purchase == "Sell") & (!Price %in% as.character(-50:150))), start = list(a=4000, b=0.1, c=-5, d=32000))
h[[i]] <- coef(f)  
}
h.df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, h), names(h[[1]]))
```

Then I just took the datas of the supply curve and the ninth hour and changed the format of the date:

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")    
df <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(files)) {
xx <- read.csv(as.character(files[i]))    
xx <- subset(xx, Sale.Purchase == "Sell" & Hour == 9)
df <- rbind(df, xx)
}
df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

And then I tried to plot the coefficient a:

```
plot(h.df$a ~ Date, df, xlim = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")))
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'Date')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are the lengths of `h.df$a` and `df$Date`?

Comment: Just a side note: you can place the function definition of `g <- function(a, b, c, d, p) {a*atan(b*p+c)+d}` outside (before) the `for` loop. As it stands, you define the function again in each iteration of the loop which isn't necessary.

Comment: Is it correct that what you are trying to plot is in two different data frames (`df` and `h.df`)? Perhaps you can create a single data.frame with both informations (mabye using `merge`) and then plot it - which might also help avoiding different lengths.

Comment: IF all your dataframes have the same columns in the same order, you should just put them all together -- e.g. via `plyr::ldply` or `do.call(rbind,alledat)`

Comment: The problem was that they had different lengths. I solved the problem with an selfmade x axis: dates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "days", length=length(h.df$a)). Thank you for your help.